# What does SQLCODE: -516 signify

Tags: sql, db2, sqlcode

I am able to retrieve data from  the same database table but am not able to isert
The error which i get is

DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -516, SQLSTATE: 26501, SQLERRMC: null

Comment: What was wrong with IBM's DB2 documentation?  What part of the reference manual for DB2 was confusing or incomplete?

Answer (score 4):

IBM's [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r2mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wps.z.620.doc/doc/rins_zos_sql204_516.html) suggests that

> the currentSchema property does not
>   match the schema name of the tables
>   and indexes that you created.

(Although the above is for z/OS, I would expect that the Java DB2 implementation is the same)

Comment: Thanks ..

Its actually ment that there is a mismatch of columns.
I was inserting 17 columns through frontend while in the backend there was one more extra coloumn.

Answer (score 2):

When you got SQLCODE that retreive from DB2
you can use following command for describe

```
DB2 ? SQL-<ERRORCODE>
```

example

```
DB2 ? sql-407
```